# Cancel = True not working on form load

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

On a form load event, I have it check the access level of the user. if it is below a certain threshold or they never signed in, then I have the line

```
Cancel = true
```

However, the form loads regardless.  Here is the entire form load event.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
If IsNull(Forms!frmUsernamePassword!txtUserName) Then
MsgBox "You need to enter a username or password first.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
Cancel = -1
ElseIf DLookup("[AccessLevel_ID]", "tblUsernamePasswords", "[txtUserName]= '" &        Forms!frmUsernamePassword!txtUserName & "'") = 1 Then
MsgBox "Your Security Level is 1", vbOKOnly
ElseIf DLookup("[AccessLevel_ID]", "tblUsernamePasswords", "[txtUserName]= '" &    Forms!frmUsernamePassword!txtUserName & "'") = 2 Then
MsgBox "Your Security Level is 2", vbOKOnly
ElseIf DLookup("[AccessLevel_ID]", "tblUsernamePasswords", "[txtUserName]= '" &     Forms!frmUsernamePassword!txtUserName & "'") = 3 Then
MsgBox "Your Security Level is 3", vbOKOnly
ElseIf DLookup("[AccessLevel_ID]", "tblUsernamePasswords", "[txtUserName]='" Forms!frmUsernamePassword!txtUserName & "'") = 4 Then
MsgBox "Your Security Level is 4", vbOKOnly
End If
End Sub
```

sorry for the formatting issures.

Comment: Form load does not have a cancel argument. Use form open for cancel. Setting contents of controls must occur in form load.

Comment: @Remou I couldn't find a duplicate. You should consider submitting your answer.

Comment: @ckuhn203 It is not a very good question, I am afraid.

Comment: @Remou No. It's not, but it's one without a canonical answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form load does not have a cancel argument. Use form open for cancel. Setting contents of controls must occur in form load.